# Wordpress Primary Menu CSS

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just finished a website
http://freelanceaccounting.co.za

Please note this is just a test domain for the website im building. It is not the correct domain name.

I am using the Education Hub Theme

Now if you look at the navigation menu. Between each page in the menu is a | how would i remove those line? or even better change the look of the menu entirely? I have looked for plugins but none seem to change a thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AT your http://freelanceaccounting.co.za/wp-content/themes/education-hub/style.css the following code part applies those | characters. You can delete border-right attribute  as below:

```
main-navigation ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    /* border-right: 1px solid #fff; commented*/ 
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Also you play with look of menu in this css. If you dont have access ftp, In wordpress you edit these css files.